# WSO2 ESB How to call different type of endpoint in proxy service

Tags: wso2, cxf, apache-axis, esb

We have four endpoints services. Three of them are SOAP web service that was developed with axis2 framework. One is REST service that was developed with CXF framework. I want to get a value from REST web service and I want to pass this value to axis2 SOAP service in proxy service. How can I do this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this requirement with service chaining in wso2 ESB (refer document [1], [2] for getting more information about service chaining).
You can first call your REST service and specify "receiving" sequence in the send mediator like below (refer [3]).

```
<inSequence>
   .............

   <send receive="soapserviceSeq">
        <endpoint key="restEpr"/>
   </send>
</inSequence>

<sequence name="soapserviceSeq">
   ........................
   <send receive="restserviceSeq">
        <endpoint key="soapEpr"/>
   </send>
</sequence>

<sequence name="restserviceSeq">
    <log level="full"/>
    <send/>
</sequence>
```

Then the response of the REST service will return to the "receiving" sequence (soapserviceSeq). Within the "soapserviceSeq" sequence, you can
Call the soap service and also you can configure the receiving sequence in the send mediator (restserviceSeq).
Then the response of the soap service will return to the receiving sequence (restserviceSeq).

[1]- http://wso2.com/library/articles/2011/01/wso2-esb-by-example-service-chaining/
[2]- http://blog.afkham.org/2012/05/wso2-esb-service-chaining.html
[3]- https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Send+Mediator